# Conditional join based on row value

Tags: sql, db2

I have department mapping table where I have specific status for specific department but different status for all the rest departments that are not in department table.

dep_table:

| country | department | status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| FIN | D1 | C |
| FIN | D2 | C |
| FIN | ** | O |
| SWE | D1 | C |

act_table:

| country | department | amt |
| --- | --- | --- |
| FIN | D1 | 16 |
| FIN | D3 | 45 |
| SWE | D1 | 13 |

expected result:

| country | department | amt | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| FIN | D1 | 16 | C |
| FIN | D3 | 45 | O |
| SWE | D1 | 13 | C |

I have this but it causes duplicated rows (because joins ** and also non-** rows):

```
SELECT t1.country, t1.department, t1.amt, t2.status
FROM act_table t1 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN dep_table t2
     ON t1.country = t2.country 
     AND CASE WHEN t1.department = t2.department THEN 1 WHEN t2.department = '**' THEN 1 END = 1
```

*(This is very simplified scenario - needs to be done in this manner.)*

Comment: You have not clarified the logic for selecting which row to match.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want `'O'` if any of the statuses are `'O'`.  If there are only two statuses, you can use a correlated subquery:

```
select a.*,
       (select d.status
        from dep_table d
        where d.country = a.country 
        order by d.status desc
        fetch first 1 row only
       ) as status
from act_table a;
```

Comment: Thank you, but no. There are more statuses and even more columns in department table. I should have specified that.

Comment: @MichalPalko . . . I would suggest that you ask a new question that more clearly specifies what you are doing.  This answers the question that you have asked here.

Answer (score 0):

I think two left joins make it more clear :

```
with
dep_table (country, department, status) as (
  values
  ('FIN', 'D1', 'C'),
  ('FIN', 'D2', 'C'),
  ('FIN', '**', 'O'),
  ('SWE', 'D1', 'C')
),
act_table (country, department, amt) as (
  values
  ('FIN', 'D2', 16),
  ('FIN', 'D3', 45),
  ('SWE', 'D1', 13)
)
select
  act.country, act.department, act.amt, coalesce(specific.status, rest.status) status
from act_table act
  left join dep_table specific using(country, department)
  left join dep_table rest on specific.status is null and (rest.country, rest.department) = (act.country, '**')
order by country, department
```

Answer (score 0):

Use olap function row_number to select first row

```
select  country ,  department ,  amt ,  status
from
(
  select a.country , a.department ,
         a.amt ,  d.status , 
         row_number() over( partition by  a.country , a.department 
                    order by  case when d.department = '**' then 1 else 0 end ) as    rn1 
    from dep_table d ,
    act_table a
    where d.country = a.country
    and   ( d.department = a.department or d.department = '**' )
) x 
where rn1 = 1
```